# Basic Win32 C programming

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to display the command line arguments.
This is my current code.

```
#include "windows.h"
int _stdcall WinMain ( HINSTANCE  hInstance,  
                       HINSTANCE  hPrevInstance,       
                       LPSTR  lpszCmdline,  
                       int  nCmdShow  )
{ 
    MessageBox (  0, lpszCmdLine,L"Title",0); 

    return  ( 0 ) ; 
}
```

I'm getting different characters in application.

What changes should I do in order to display the command line arguments in application window?

Comment: Never saw this syntax in C, and I coded in C for a while :o

Comment: Do you have the `UNICODE` macro defined? Then `MessageBox` is really `MessageBoxW` which is the wide character `wchar_t` variant. And `LPSTR` is still `char *`, which is a *narrow* character string. The compiler should complain about that IIRC.

Comment: @Simo Legit code for Win API..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was just wondering

Comment: Im using vs-2010 ,Unicode might be defined in winuser.h

Comment: @user9104371: It would be defined in **your** project. But show us the actual error message; that stops us from guessing.

Comment: I'm a newbie to stack overflow,I don't have enough reputation to upload photo

Comment: @MSalters The different characters (Japanese/Chinese) are getting displayed onto the application window

Comment: You are calling a Unicode version of `MessageBox`. `lpszCmdline` is being interpreted as pointing to a wide character string. Every two ASCII characters are treated as a single Unicode character; purely by accident, that character lands in CJK code block (well, not really by accident; that code block is a large chunk of Unicode space, so a randomly selected character has a high chance of landing there). In C++, you would be getting a type mismatch error; but C allows implicit conversion between any two pointer types.

Answer (score -2):

Since lpszCmdline is LPSTR, (ASCII, not UNICODE), the first option would be using the ASCII version of MessageBox(), but since UNICODE is the standard, I would suggest using the UNICODE version of win32 [entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point). See the code below:

```
#include "windows.h"
int _stdcall wWinMain ( HINSTANCE  hInstance,  
                       HINSTANCE  hPrevInstance,       
                       LPWSTR  lpszCmdline,  
                       int  nCmdShow  )
{ 
    MessageBox (  0, lpszCmdLine,L"Title",0); 

    return  ( 0 ) ; 
}
```

Further more, to convert the command line to an argv style array of strings, call the [CommandLineToArgvW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point) function.

Comment: Arguably, the easiest and **correct** way would be implement a Unicode entry point, called `wWinMain` when using Microsoft's compiler. That entry point gets the command line as a wide character string.

Comment: This is still wrong, and somewhat misleading. There is no ASCII in the Windows API. If there was, there would be no ambiguity. But it's ANSI, which makes all the difference. And there's no need to call `CommandLineToArgvW` either, when using Visual Studio. You already get the parsed out command line arguments as [`__argc, __argv, __wargv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv). Plus, the signature is using the wrong calling convention. That should be `WINAPI`.